# Adding Mutiple Measures on same axis

Tags: tableau-api

I am new to tableau. And I am exploring some of its features. I wanted to have multiple measures on the same axis but not as aggregation but as dimensions. I have explored dual axis as well but I wanted to add third and fourth measure as a dimension. I had gone through some discussion but they only add aggregation function within measure_values, even if I drag & drop my measure in the axis it either show nothing or make an aggregation function of my measure. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use measure as a dimension,convert that measure to dimension.
In the data pane, right click on that measure and select Convert to Dimension.
Hope this is what you are looking at.